# How to align images as shown in the screenshot?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

How to align images as shown in the screenshot, *Note:* The images are from backend..
  [image: please check this image]

I tried this code and position the images with top,right,left,bottom properties 
but if the number of images increases lead to rework on the html code and css.. uses the nth-child property but it create a problem in responsive checking.. It is needed to upload the images from backend on the correct position

```
     <ul class="box-image">
    <li>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="img/item1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="hold-text">
          <h3>Al Raha Beach Villa
            Abu Dhabi 204264</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="img/item2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="hold-text">
          <h3>Al Raha Beach Villa
            Abu Dhabi 204264</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="img/item3.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="hold-text">
          <h3>Al Raha Beach Villa
            Abu Dhabi 204264</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="img/item4.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="hold-text">
          <h3>Al Raha Beach Villa
            Abu Dhabi 204264</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="img/item5.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="hold-text">
          <h3>Al Raha Beach Villa
            Abu Dhabi 204264</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="img/item6.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="hold-text">
          <h3>Al Raha Beach Villa
            Abu Dhabi 204264</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="img/item7.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="hold-text">
          <h3>Al Raha Beach Villa
            Abu Dhabi 204264</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="img/item8.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="hold-text">
          <h3>Al Raha Beach Villa
            Abu Dhabi 204264</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="img/item9.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="hold-text">
          <h3>Al Raha Beach Villa
            Abu Dhabi 204264</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: you need to share your code with us. show what you have done.

Comment: i wanna align the images like this ( please refer screenshot image)..

Comment: Recently i used monosry plugin... but the problem arises  when the number of images increases it does'nt work... becoz the images are upadated through backend... how to count the images to align like this....

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this using `column` property of css3. You can break Images as well  Text using the `column` property in css3. Using `column-count`, you can specify the number of columns to which you want to break the images into.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/abinthaha/pen/ayOjmw)

You can refer the sample that I tried using `column-count: 3` which broke the images into 3 columns.

HTML coding

```
<div class='container'>
  <span class='image-wrapper'>
    <img src="https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/picture-element/images/butterfly.webp" />
  </span>
  <span class='image-wrapper'>
    <img src="https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/picture-element/images/butterfly.webp" />
  </span>
  <span class='image-wrapper'>
    <img src="https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/picture-element/images/butterfly.webp" />
  </span>
  <span class='image-wrapper'>
    <img src="https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/picture-element/images/butterfly.webp" />
  </span>
  <span class='image-wrapper'>
    <img src="https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/picture-element/images/butterfly.webp" />
  </span>
</div>
```

CSS Styling

```
.container {
  column-count: 3;
}
```

Comment: Its fine, but i need the second column alignment as in the image

Comment: Does the number of columns always will be 3?

Comment: Otherwise, you can use flexbox. But you will need to split your images from backend and put into each column before showing it.

Comment: ya.. if number of images increases they are aligned to the next row